# privacyIDEA send noti QR Code via email

Tags: sendmail, qr-code, one-time-password

Can you help me?
I used privacyIDEA create HOTP and trying to send the QR code as an email, but it simply doesn't display in the email client.

I config Event Handler User Notification:

Events: token_init

Handlermodule: UserNotification

Action: sendmail

To: tokenowner

body:

Hi {givenname} {surname},

You may use the OTP value your new token {serial}.

QR Code

Admin.

Mimetype: html

Error mail client: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GhTj.jpg)

Thanks,

Toàn Nguyễn

Comment: Obviously you entered some html code, that is not visible here!

Answer (score 0):

you need to add a **tag** in the body of the email.
Take a look here at the online documentation:
http://privacyidea.readthedocs.io/en/latest/eventhandler/usernotification.html#options-for-both-actions

You need to use the tag `{googleurl_img}`, which will add the QR Code as an image to the html mail.

Note: Sending it via email is a bad idea, since the qr code contains the secret key in **clear text**!. However, you could also add `{googleurl_value}` which will add the contents of the qr code as link. On a smartphone you could "click" this link.

But again note: This should only be part of a more sophisticated enrollment process, since sending the secret key via an email is **a bad idea**.

Kind regards
Cornelius

Comment: Thanks Cornelius,
I used the tag <img src={googleurl_img}> into body but not display images email

Comment: That should do the trick. At least it does in other setups. So you should check the source of the email, then you would see what is up.